# Rails lookup form using drop down field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, activerecord, select

I imagine this should be very straight forward and after fruitless searching it seems that it might be too simple!

I have two models: :client and :job. A client has many jobs and jobs belongs to clients.

In my routes.rb I have a nested resource as follows:

```
resources :client do
  resources :job 
end
```

The following path when manually entered resolves no problem:

```
/client/:client_id/job
```

What I want to have is a simple one-field drop down selection form on the job index page that lists all the clients and when submitted points to the above path with the selected client_id.

I have the following form in view/job/index.erb

```
<%= form_tag( client_index_path, :action => 'index', :method => 'get' ) do %>
  <%= collection_select ("job", "client_id", Client.all, "id", "name", {:include_blank => 'Filter by client'}) %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Go' %>
<% end %>
```

which on submission resolves to:

```
/client?utf8=✓&job%5Bclient_id%5D=2&commit=Go
```

This is the HTML generated by rails:

```
<select id="job_client_id" name="job[client_id]">
  <option value="">Filter by client</option>
  <option value="1">client1</option>
  <option value="2">client1</option>
  <option value="3">client2</option>
</select>
```

Any help greatly appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this via pure html without any javascript. Forms always submit to one URL, with any data being supplied via POST or GET parameters (that's the stuff after the /client?).

There are two options.

If you can rely on javascript being enabled, then hijack the submit button to construct the URL. Something like this:

```
$("#form").submit(function(){
  client_id = $("#job_client_id").val();
  window.location = '/client/' + client_id + '/job/';
  return false; // don't sumbmit the form
})
```

**EDIT**: here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Fj5Kh/1/

Your second option is to actually submit the form to the server, and do a redirect there. That's an extra server call, but it will work without javascript.  You'd create a special controller action that understands the form and use a `redirect_to` line

Comment: Thanks Spike! Think I'm almost there with the javascript solution. Do I need to add in a onsubmit or action to the form too?

Comment: yea, sorry, I had used jquery for my sample code since it's more condensed. If you're using pure JS you'll want to set an onsubmit handler for the form (that's what $("#form").submit(handler) does if you have jQuery loaded).

Comment: Ah great thanks - I have jquery loaded. It doesn't seem to be picking up the selected value still. I've tried to debug and it seems that I can get the first selected text value of the dropdown (using .text and the second half of your function) but when I replace it with .value it doesn't return the selected value. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: see my edit for an example of getting the value from a select box

Comment: Thanks again for that Spike. I got your example working for a simple form, but when I switch it to use the rails generated form the alert returns 'undefined'. The HTML that rails generates looks exactly the same as the example, so I'm not sure what's happening. If you have more time then any more advice would be great, but understand if you've already spent enough already!

Comment: Can you append the html that rails generates to your question? That will make it possible for me or someone else to help further.

Comment: Added the HTML. The alert now returns empty rather than undefined

Comment: see my updated JSfiddle link, hope that helps.  replace "#example" with the id of the form that rails generated

Comment: Thanks Spike. I eventually got something working this morning, but strangely it was the trailing '_id' of the selection name that seemed to be causing the issue. I changed 'job_client_id' to 'job_client_name' and it worked. I can only seem to get the javascript to fire on route /job/new, so there might be an issue with where I've stored my js, but that's a whole new story. Thanks again for your help